# What does $0.9999\ldots$ equal in the deleted integer positive Reals?

Tags: real-analysis

If one takes the positive real numbers and removes the integers, $\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0} \setminus \mathbb{Z}$, the number $0.9999\ldots$ exists by definition but the integer 1 does not. No tricky proofs will make $0.9999\ldots=1$ because $1$ is undefined in $\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0} \setminus \mathbb{Z}$. Does anyone have any idea on how to find the answer to $0.9999\ldots = ?$ in this set of numbers?

I'm not a trained mathematician, I only like thinking about it for fun. If there's anything naive or wrong in the premise, please explain it to me.

Thanks,

Holly

Comment: "*exists by definition*" What definition?

Comment: It's a non-convergent Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Z$.

Comment: I think you are assuming that all sets are closed under limits. This is not true; for example the decimal expansion of pi provides a sequence of rational numbers approximating an irrational number

Comment: @dxiv, the definition of the Real numbers > 0 (with or without the integers)

Comment: @instroyer where in that sentence does one find the definition of $0.999\dots$?

Comment: @instroyer By the standard "*definition of the* ***Real*** *numbers*", the number $0.999\dots$ represents the integer $1$, which is not in $\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0} \setminus \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @instroyer: Which definition are you using?  Dedekind cuts, Cauchy sequences, what?  It may be that the definition of the reals is not as clear to you as you think.

Comment: Specifically, the use of the ellipsis ($\ldots$) implies a limit.  In this case, we may consider $0.999\ldots$ to be the limit of the sequence $0.9, 0.99, 0.999, \ldots$.  This limit is unambiguously $1$, which means that if we consider the set $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Z}$, the sequence is in that set, but its limit is not.

Comment: How do you define the real numbers?

Comment: Thank you for clarifying @BrianTung, I haven't fully learned the formal definitions of the reals and misused definite language in my question. Your second comment and Bungo's comment help me understand this set more, thanks

Comment: For the sake of the unique representation of reals by $p$-adic numbers one should explicitly forbid representations finally ending in period $p-1$.

Answer (score 3):

In fact, one has $0.9999\ldots = 1$, as you noticed. Consequently, $0.9999\ldots$ belongs to $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: You're saying if you were working in the deleted integer positive reals, you couldn't use or encounter 0.9999 ... ?

Comment: @instroyer: You would have to define what the ellipsis $\ldots$ *means* in this instance.  It is simply not precise enough to just say "it goes on forever."  The field axioms do not admit of infinite additions, so one must make use of analytical arguments (e.g., limits).

Comment: @BrianTung This makes sense, but it's opening up a lot more questions about this number set that I don't have the training to clearly ask.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, the expression $0.999 \ldots$ is simply undefined in $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Z}$. I want to elaborate slightly on this. When we write $0.a_1 a_2 a_3 \ldots$, where $a_k \in \{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 \}$, we are referring to the limit of the sequence $\left( \sum_{k = 1}^n a_k 10^{-k} \right)_{n = 1}^\infty = (0.a_1 \ldots a_n)_{n = 1}^\infty$. This limit always exists in $\mathbb{R}$ because $\mathbb{R}$ has a property called *completeness*, a property which can be understood in several different but equivalent ways. But $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Z}$ is not complete, so some limits which might exist in $\mathbb{R}$ don’t exist in $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Z}$, and this here is one such example.

EDIT: This could be interpreted as a reason to think that $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Z}$ is simply not as interesting as $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

You might as well ask what's $\sqrt{2}=1.414213562\ldots$ in $\Bbb Q$. It, like $\Bbb R_{\ge0}\setminus\Bbb Z$, isn't [complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_metric_space) with respect to the Euclidean metric used to define e.g. $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n9/10^k$. So for both problems, the requested limit doesn't exist in the given space.